# How to make a restrictive syscall *whitelist* with systemd-nspawn?

Tags: container, systemd-nspawn, seccomp

I'm trying to lock down a container using `systemd-nspawn`, so that *only* the specific syscalls I whitelist are allowed.  Per [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html), there's a pretty lax filter in place by default, consisting of a large whitelist of hundreds of different system calls.  There's a unit option `SystemCallFilter=`, which claims to allow you to blacklist or whitelist specific calls.  I tried it out, putting a single syscall on there and expecting complete failure:

```
[Exec]
...
# We use way more syscalls than this! This whitelist should fail, but it doesn't because it's not a real whitelist.
SystemCallFilter=open,write,close
...
```

Instead, the program runs just fine.  I can get it to fail if I explicitly disallow a syscall I know is in use:

```
[Exec]
...
# This actually fails, because open's been explicitly blacklisted.
SystemCallFilter=~open,~write
...
```

Also, because the blacklist takes precedence over the "whitelist," I can't just disable everything and then turn back on only the ones I need; the whitelist is just ignored:

```
[Exec]
...
# Doesn't work, as ~@default takes precedence over the allowlist so *nothing* is allowed
SystemCallFilter=~@default
# full list is much longer and generated automatically from a docker seccomp .json
SystemCallFilter=open,write,close,...
```

Is there a way to achieve the functionality I want?  I really don't want to maintain a blacklist of all of the hundreds of syscalls on the default allowlist, which seems like the only way to do it currently.

Comment: Are you starting a docker container with that? If your unit invokes docker the entire exercise is pointless since docker actually delegates everything to its privileged dockerd process.

Comment: No, I'm starting a `systemd-nspawn` with a `.nspawn` file in `/etc/systemd/nspawn/servicename.nspawn`.  I'm trying to replace Docker with `systemd-nspawn` and port over my seccomp.json security profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Well 1st off make sure seccomp is enabled .. as per systemd-exec some calls are always allowed.. exec, write, open ,read and a host of others are allowed .. SystemCallFilter= works , make your life easy add `SystemCallLog=~chown` or any unknown used system call and all syscalls used will be logged. Search them in `journalctl _AUDIT_TYPE_NAME=SECCOMP`..

your answer detail is found here.

```
--system-call-filter=

    Alter the system call filter applied to containers. Takes a space-separated list of system call names or group names (the latter prefixed with "@", as listed by the syscall-filter command of systemd-analyze(1)). Passed system calls will be permitted. The list may optionally be prefixed by "~", in which case all listed system calls are prohibited. If this command line option is used multiple times the configured lists are combined. If both a positive and a negative list (that is one system call list without and one with the "~" prefix) are configured, the negative list takes precedence over the positive list. Note that systemd-nspawn always implements a system call allow list (as opposed to a deny list!), and this command line option hence adds or removes entries from the default allow list, depending on the "~" prefix. Note that the applied system call filter is also altered implicitly if additional capabilities are passed using the --capabilities=.`enter code here
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-nspawn.html